# Canvas clear screen

Tags: android, android-canvas

I use this method to clear screen

```
Canvas canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
canvas.drawPaint(p);
p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

but it now work, and screen blink.

and then I using

```
for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    Canvas canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawPaint(p);
    p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

It works, and why?

Comment: you have to invalidate view after any change .

Comment: call postInvalidate() after unlockCanvasAndPost(), also flicker..